# -[_UIFlowLayoutSection center]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

How can I fix this crash:

> -[_UIFlowLayoutSection center]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.

I am doing:

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *collectionLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];    
collectionLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0.0;    
collectionLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0.0;    
collectionLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);    
[collectionLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];    
[_collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:collectionLayout];
```

Comment: Even i got the same crash, but don't know how to solve it. Have you solved the crash, please help me.

Answer (score 5):

try to reload the collectionView before setting it's flowlayout.

i was having the same issue and was resolved by reloading the collectionView before setting flowlayout.

Comment: yes bro, yesterday only i solved it, in the similar way as you have mentioned and i supposed to post the answer today, but i am late. No problem i am up voting your answer.